# How to send a shape to front in Aspose.Words

Tags: c#, aspose, aspose.words

I am placing a watermark on a Document, but sometimes the watermark ends up behind some image and I can't bring it to front. I tried to set the ZOrderPosition and ZOrder property to high values like 99 but it still not in front of everything else.

Comment: Regarding Aspose.Cells, if your image is inside header and footer as shared by Awais, then you cannot bring it to front. For other cases, please share your Excel file so that we could look into this issue further. --- Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: Turns out it was a Chart actually, not a spreadsheet with an image, but I still can't place a watermark there. I edited this question to target only the aspose.words issue, and I will make another one targeting the chart problem.

Comment: Yes, the separate post/topic that targets only Aspose.Cells will both be useful and helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs because watermark shape resides inside header footer story of Word document and main content is inside body story (please see [Story class](https://apireference.aspose.com/net/words/aspose.words/story/)). If you insert a watermark using Microsoft Word 2016, you will observe the same behavior. All content of document's header/footer is always behind the main content of the document.

However, you may overcome this problem by manually inserting watermarks in each Page. You can achieve this by moving the cursor to the first Run in each Page of your document and then making those Runs as an anchor points for your watermarks. Please see the following code for example:

```
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + @"input.doc");

Node[] runs = doc.GetChildNodes(NodeType.Run, true).ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < runs.Length; i++)
{
    Run run = (Run)runs[i];
    int length = run.Text.Length;

    Run currentNode = run;
    for (int x = 1; x < length; x++)
    {
        currentNode = SplitRun(currentNode, 1);
    }
}

DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
PageSetup ps = builder.PageSetup;

NodeCollection smallRuns = doc.GetChildNodes(NodeType.Run, true);
LayoutCollector collector = new LayoutCollector(doc);

int pageIndex = 1;
foreach (Run run in smallRuns)
{
    if (collector.GetStartPageIndex(run) == pageIndex)
    {
        Shape watermark = new Shape(doc, Aspose.Words.Drawing.ShapeType.TextPlainText);
        watermark.RelativeHorizontalPosition = RelativeHorizontalPosition.Page;
        watermark.RelativeVerticalPosition = RelativeVerticalPosition.Page;

        watermark.Width = 300;
        watermark.Height = 70;
        watermark.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        watermark.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

        watermark.Rotation = -40;
        watermark.Fill.Color = Color.Gray;
        watermark.StrokeColor = Color.Gray;

        watermark.TextPath.Text = "watermarkText";
        watermark.TextPath.FontFamily = "Arial";

        watermark.Name = string.Format("WaterMark_{0}", Guid.NewGuid());
        watermark.WrapType = WrapType.None;

        builder.MoveTo(run);
        builder.InsertNode(watermark);

        pageIndex++;
    }
}

doc.Save(MyDir + @"output\18.3.doc");
///////////////////////////////////////
private static Run SplitRun(Run run, int position)
{
    Run afterRun = (Run)run.Clone(true);
    afterRun.Text = run.Text.Substring(position);
    run.Text = run.Text.Substring((0), (0) + (position));
    run.ParentNode.InsertAfter(afterRun, run);
    return afterRun;
}
```

Hope, this helps. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed my problem for Word Documents!